# Error when installing kibana , "module not found"

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have dowloaded kibana 8.11.2 and elasticsearch 8.11.2 but I'm I'm running the command kibana.bat in the path :D/elasinstall/kibana8.11.2/bin , I come across this error message :
D:\elkinstaller\kibana-8.11.2\bin>kibana.bat
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\elkinstaller\kibana-8.11.2\src\cli\dist'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.18.2
and  wonder how can I fix it?

I have tried deleting and reinstalling and it's the same problem , and i also tried to execute the command as an administrator but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting your archive once more as it seems that for some reason, the folder 'src\cli\dist' is missing.

Be sure that the folder is there before running the command kibana.bat.